# How to store IoT data into Amazon RDS MySQL database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am using 20 devices and devices are connected with AWS IoT core (broker). They are publishing data at the rate of 3s.

I want to store all devices data into my database. Can you guys help me or suggest me a better architecture? Which database is good for me. If RDS is good, then how to store data into it which is coming from IoT devices?

Comment: Are you sure you wish to store all these values? 20 devices sending data every 3 seconds is 576,000 data points per day. If you need them, then you can store them no problem, but the quantities can add-up pretty quickly. An alternative is to use Amazon Kinesis to analyze the incoming data streams and 'react' to any out-of-bounds values.

Comment: Before being able to recommend a database to store the IoT data, the important question is **how are you going to _use_ the data?** This will determine whether to use a relational database (eg Amazon RDS) or a NoSQL database (eg Amazon DynamoDB). Do you need to analyze data 'on the fly', or is it all simply being stored for later analysis? It might be easier to store the data in Amazon S3 rather than a database, depending upon your requirements.